# Not able to install python via Pyenv on a M2 Max Studio Mac. Complaining about architecture x86_64

Tags: python

I am using a Mac Studio M2 Max OS 14.4
I am having the world of trouble installing python. I have tried the following with no luck:
create new account in my machine
several times->
installed Pyenv, anaconda, python via brew.

```
pyenv install 3.11
```

---

> python-build: use openssl@3 from homebrew python-build: use readline
> from homebrew Downloading Python-3.11.8.tar.xz...
> -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.8/Python-3.11.8.tar.xz Installing Python-3.11.8... python-build: use readline from homebrew
> python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
> BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.4 using python-build 20180424)
>
> Inspect or clean up the working tree at
> /var/folders/h7/cvnzd8pn3v77yd6nt8_t7j5c0000gp/T/python-build.20240309141906.38567
> Results logged to
> /var/folders/h7/cvnzd8pn3v77yd6nt8_t7j5c0000gp/T/python-build.20240309141906.38567.log
>
> Last 10 log lines:
> __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
> __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
> __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o   "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
> __locale_textdomain in _localemodule.o
> **ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64** clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make: *** [Programs/_freeze_module] Error 1 make: *** Waiting for
> unfinished jobs.... 2 warnings generated.